# Hyperlinks in MS Word not clickable on touchscreen

Tags: microsoft-word, hyperlink, touchscreen

I am using Office 365. I have found that, in MS Word, a hyperlink in a Word document is not 'clickable' on a touchscreen, whereas it *will* work with a mouse. Hyperlinks in Excel work fine with touch. Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this, please?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Word, so maybe my "fix" will work for you.  I was trying to tap the **touchscreen** as the "click" when the link was highlighted and CTRL held down.  Nothing happened. Instead, try highlighting the link with the touchscreen as usual, then hold down CTRL and use the ***touch pad*** instead of the screen as the "click".
Hope it works for you.

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only person who has had this problem!  Thank you for your comments. Unfortunately this won't work for the individual I have set up the system (a calendar with links to photos) for. She has a disability following a brain injury and manages best with a simple touch or tap when using a computer, I think CTRL plus tap would be too much for her. I had removed the need to use CTRL in settings, to simplify the process and was dismayed when I found that hyperlinks wouldn't work with touch! Am using Excel for now, but may need to find another program.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on my Dell 5285 with touchscreen in Windows 10:

1. First I disabled the [Ctrl]-click option
2. Then I highlighted the whole hyperlink (double click at the end, then at the beginning)
3. Then a long press on the highlighted link
4. Upon release a popup window opens with format options: on the right side there is a small downward arrow: click
5. A second windows pops up with the option to open the link (for me the second from the top)

Answer (score -1):

In her Word application try:
File | Options | Advanced | uncheck Use CTRL + Click to follow hyperlink.

Comment: Hi

Thanks for thinking about this. I have tried this solution and have removed the need for CTRL. However, the issue is that, whilst a single mouse click will activate the hyperlink (no Control key required), a tap on a touchscreen won't do it.